# Memory allocation failed : growing buffer - Python

Tags: python, html, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I'm working on a script which scrapes thousands of different web pages. Since these pages are usually different (has different sites), I use multithreading to speed up scraping.

**EDIT:  SIMPLE SHORT EXPLANATION**

*-------*

*I'm loading 300 urls (htmls) in one pool of 300 workers. Since the size of html is variable, sometimes, the sum of sizes is probably too big and python raises: `internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer`. I want to somehow check if this can happend and if, wait until the buffer is not full.*

*-------*

This approach works but sometimes, python starts to throw:

```
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
```

into console. I suppose that it is because of size of `html` I store in memory, which can be 300*(for example 1mb) = 300mb

**EDIT:**

*I know that I can decrease number of workers and I will. But it's not a solution, there would be just lower chance to get such error. I want to avoid this error at all...*

I started to log `html` sizes:

```
ram_logger.debug('SIZE: {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(html)))
```

And the result is (part):

```
2017-03-05 13:02:04,914 DEBUG SIZE: 243940
2017-03-05 13:02:05,023 DEBUG SIZE: 138384
2017-03-05 13:02:05,026 DEBUG SIZE: 1185964
2017-03-05 13:02:05,141 DEBUG SIZE: 1203715
2017-03-05 13:02:05,213 DEBUG SIZE: 291415
2017-03-05 13:02:05,213 DEBUG SIZE: 287030
2017-03-05 13:02:05,224 DEBUG SIZE: 1192165
2017-03-05 13:02:05,230 DEBUG SIZE: 1193751
2017-03-05 13:02:05,234 DEBUG SIZE: 359193
2017-03-05 13:02:05,247 DEBUG SIZE: 23703
2017-03-05 13:02:05,252 DEBUG SIZE: 24606
2017-03-05 13:02:05,275 DEBUG SIZE: 302388
2017-03-05 13:02:05,329 DEBUG SIZE: 334925
```

This is my simplified scraping approach:

```
def scrape_chunk(chunk):
    pool = Pool(300)
    results = pool.map(scrape_chunk_item, chunk)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

def scrape_chunk_item(item):
    root_result = _load_root(item.get('url'))
    # parse using xpath and return
```

And the function to load html:

```
def _load_root(url):
    for i in xrange(settings.ENGINE_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS):
        try:
            headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
            headers['User-Agent'] = ua.chrome
            r = requests.get(url, timeout=(settings.ENGINE_SCRAPER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT + i, 10 + i), verify=False, )
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.Timeout as e:

            if i >= settings.ENGINE_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS - 1:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                return {'success': False, 'root': None, 'error': 'timeout', 'traceback': tb}
        except Exception:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            return {'success': False, 'root': None, 'error': 'unknown_error', 'traceback': tb}
        else:
            break

    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
    html = r.content
    ram_logger.debug('SIZE: {}'.format(sys.getsizeof(html)))
    try:
        root = etree.fromstring(html, etree.HTMLParser())
    except Exception:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        return {'success': False, 'root': None, 'error': 'root_error', 'traceback': tb}

    return {'success': True, 'root': root}
```

Do you know how to make it safe? Something which make workers wait if there would be buffer overflow problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? The only answer was not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit each worker to start only if there is X memory available...
**not tested**

```
lock = threading.Lock()
total_mem= 1024 * 1024 * 500 #500MB spare memory
@contextlib.contextmanager
def ensure_memory(size):
    global total_mem
    while 1:
        with lock:
            if total_mem > size:
                total_mem-= size
                break
        time.sleep(1) #or something else...
    yield 
    with lock:
        total_mem += size

def _load_root(url):
    ...
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=(settings.ENGINE_SCRAPER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT + i, 10 + i), verify=False, stream=True) #add the stream=True to make request wait on on loading the entire request
    ...
    with ensure_memory(r.headers['content-length']):
        #now do stuff here :)
        html = r.content 
        ...
        return {'success': True, 'root': root}
```

total_mem can be also auto-computed so you won't have to guess what is the right value for each machine ...